# What if there is no GemFile in the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the application from other developer, while i'm executing it through

```
     bundle exec rails server
```

It give's me error of **Could not locate Gemfile**

now What should i do?

Comment: Is there a `Gemfile` in the main directory?  There should be, since Rails generates a Gemfile.

Comment: Ask the other developer what they did to your app?

Comment: there is no Gemfile in the root directory. Developer is not answering, He just forwarded me a package without the Gemfile. Is there any other solution to it ?

Comment: Could it be a very old rails app from before bundler?

Comment: Rails started using bundler in version 3. This is likely a Rails 2 app.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run command

```
bundle init
```

it will generate a Gemfile with the default rubygems.org source.

Comment: thanks @saravanan, however i tried this command and yes it creates the GemFile, but it give's me this error: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:256:in `block in replace_gem': rake is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: add this gem 'rake', '~> 10.1.0' to your gem file.then run command bundle

Comment: Also, you'll need to be aware that your current environment is partly controlled by `rvm` (notice the `/usr/local/rvm` path), so look that up and make sure you have the latest version and so on. RVM (ruby version manager) works in concert with Bundler (which manages the gems specified in `Gemfile`).

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr i've did that but it give's me this error: [http://pastebin.com/argbwH6x](http://pastebin.com/argbwH6x)

Comment: I realized from your pastebin that you're doing this on Windows. It's certainly possible, but for this sort of problem, it's quite likely that there's some configuration needed -- a path perhaps.  I do my dev and deployment in unixy worlds so am unqualified to answer further.

Answer (score 0):

Gemfile in a rails application is used to manage gem versions used in your application.
For Gemfile maintenance have a look [here](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html) .
Gemfile require at least one gem source, in the form of the URL for a `Rubygems` server. Generate a Gemfile with the default rubygems.org source by running `bundle init` .

Bundler is a dependency management tool used for ruby development. Bundler reads your gemfile and install the required gems.

You need to have a Gemfile in your application root directory for bundler to work.